# Panning Panaroma picture in BG

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I am making a website for a restaurant. The owners took a panoramic picture of the inside and want it in the site's BG panning/skimming over the panaroma. So basically the panaroma would be the BG and would need to be rotating or panning over the image. Is this possible? I was thinking maybe with some sort of jQuery that would change the position of the image in slow motion or something, but not every adequate with jQuery to come up with the needed code. I almost resorted to animate.css but I need at least IE8 and above browser compatibility.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: It's possible, just change the CSS background position in a timer loop.

Comment: Thanks @Diodeus! What would the code look like for that?

Comment: Why not give them something even better than they imagined with a parallax animation. There are several plugins to choose from - I like [this one](http://stephband.info/jparallax/index.html). There's some work in preparing the layers but it's worth the effort.

Comment: Whoa, the parallax stuff is amazing! I love it a lot. I will definitely look into it.

Comment: The other great one is [Spritely](http://www.spritely.net/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the poor-man's version:

```
​.slide {
 height:160px;
 width:50px;
 background-position:160px 0;    
 background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/vdDQgb.jpg)  
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="slide"></div>
<div id="num"></div>
```

JS:

```
var limit = 60;
var start = 120;    
var moveBy = 1;    
var timer1 = setInterval(function() {  
    $('#num').text(start);
    $('.slide').css('background-position',start+'px 0') ;
    start--;
    if(start<0) {
       alert("done"); 
       clearTimeout(timer1);
    }    
},50)
```

Comment: Wow, works a charm! Two more questions, any way to have it loop and make it so the scrollbars don't appear since the width would surpass the browser width? I modified the code a tad bit and love it: http://jsfiddle.net/neMb8/2/

Comment: Wrap the slider in a DIV that has overflow:hidden. The code you'll have to figure out yourself from this example.

Comment: Thanks @diodeus, so it's not possible to loop it?

Comment: I am willing to pay you if you are interested. airmanstudios [at]gmail[dot]com

Answer (score 1):

To make it pan around nice and smooth for modern browsers you really should take a look at canvas since it supports 'half' pixels. I know this won't work in IE8 but the difference between jumping whole pixels and interpolating between them is huge. See http://www.willmcgugan.com/blog/tech/2011/2/26/ken-burns-effect-with-javascript-and-canvas/ for some example javascript (jQuery) of the ken burns effect in canvas.

Maybe a non canvas fallback for IE8 would be an option, for example moving a relatively positioned image  around by altering top and left css properties?

Comment: Thanks. That is definitely an option. Maybe I didn't explain myself well, but I mean pan as in this... say the image is x to y long, I want it to start from y or x and move to the opposite end of the horizontal image in a straight line like x-----y. Hope that makes sense. :)